# Wrapping multi-line custom header using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using a react-navigation stack navigator embedded in a drawer navigator.  I would like to be able to have two lines for the header text if the header text is long.  Here is what I have tried:

```
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        title: (
            <Text 
                numberOfLines = {2}
            >
                Let's see how long the title can be
            </Text>
        ),
        headerTitleStyle: 
            {
                color: Colors.ORANGE, 
            },
        headerTintColor: Colors.ORANGE,
        headerRight: 
          <MenuIcon 
              navigation = {navigation}  
          />,
    };
};
```

This doesn't work. Instead, the title is displayed as "Let's see how lo...".  When I try to create a similar text component in one of my screens, it wraps the text as intended.

How can I implement a multi-line title using react-navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I finally used to have 2 lines of text in the title:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: (
                <View 
                    style = {{width: 220, height: 50}}
                >
                    <Text 
                        numberOfLines = {2} 
                        style = {{color: Colors.ORANGE, fontWeight: '700', fontSize: 14, textAlign: 'center', marginRight: 60, marginTop: 12}}
                    >
                        Let's see how long the title can be
                    </Text>
                </View>
            ),
            headerTintColor: Colors.ORANGE,
            headerRight: 
          <MenuIcon 
              navigation = {navigation}  
          />,
        };
    }
```

Comment: Update: This works fine in iOS but I'm having trouble getting this to work in Android on RN v0.47.

Answer (score 3):

There are two properties which affect the title of the navigation bar: `title`, a plain string, and `headerTitle`, a react Component which receives the title as the `children` prop, allowing you to override how it is rendered. In this case, to make the title render on two lines you add the following to your `navigationOptions`:

```
headerTitle: ({ style, children : title }) => {
  return (
    <Text style={style} numberOfLines={2}>{title}</Text>
  )
},
```

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately this just didn't display at all and was blank.

Answer (score 0):

A fixed `width` of the header does not work well on all screen sizes.

What I did was to set percentage width and set the position absolute.

```
const HeaderTitle = (props) => {

  return <Text
        style={{
          width    : "80%",
          position : "absolute",
          top      : 0,
        }}
        numberOfLines={2}
        {...props}>
          {props.children}
        </Text>
}

navigationOptions : ({ screenProps: { t } }) => ({
  headerTitle : () => <HeaderTitle>This is a very very long headertitle, that you can choose to break into multiple lines by changing numberOfLines property</HeaderTitle>,
}),
```

[image]

[image]

[image]